# Reassign variable to original value (defined prior to the loop) at start of each iteration in loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, iteration, variable-assignment

In Python, you use `[:]` when reassigning a variable to an original value (defined prior to the loop) at the start of each iteration. That is to say:

```
original_1D = ['o', 'o', 'o']
for i in range(0,3):
  new = original_1D[:]       # revert back to 'original_1D' list defined before loop
  new[i] = 'X'
  print new
```

produces output that is both desired and expected:

```
['X', 'o', 'o']
['o', 'X', 'o']
['o', 'o', 'X']
```

My issue arises if the original list is multi-dimensional (`original_2D`). For example:

```
original_2D = [['o', 'o', 'o'],['o', 'o', 'o']]
for i in range(0,3):
  new = original_2D[:]       # revert back to 'original_2D' list defined before loop
  new[0][i] = 'X'
  print new
```

From this, I want the following output:

```
# Desired
[['X', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
[['o', 'X', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
[['o', 'o', 'X'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
```

but no! I get this:

```
# Actual
[['X', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
[['X', 'X', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
[['X', 'X', 'X'], ['o', 'o', 'o']]
```

as if the `original_2D` list gets overwritten which each iteration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Python, you use `[:]` when reassigning a variable to an original value

No, you use it to create a full-length slice (i.e. **shallow copy**) of a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). If the original value is an immutable sequence (e.g. strings and tuples) it's unnecessary, and if the original value isn't a sequence it won't work.

Note that I have emphasised *shallow copy* above - the new object created by the slice contains references to *the same objects as the original*. If your original sequence contains references to mutable objects (like, for example, lists), this can be a problem.

Either use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create a deep (rather than shallow) copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

new = deepcopy(original2D)
```

or explicitly create shallow copies of the sub-lists too, using e.g. a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
new = [row[:] for row in original2D]
```

The former scales more easily to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In python lists are always passed by object reference. So if you copy a list of lists like you did, you will still have the same list references in your list. You have to make a deep copy to solve your problem. Import the following package and change the line `new = original_2D[:]` to:

```
from copy import deepcopy

original_2D = [['o', 'o', 'o'],['o', 'o', 'o']]
for i in range(0,3):
    new = deepcopy(original_2D) # Change this line.
    new[0][i] = 'X'
    print new
```

Comment: lists are *called by reference*?

Comment: @Jasper Passed by object reference? Or what do you suggest is the right description?

Comment: See e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
original_2D = [['o', 'o', 'o'],['o', 'o', 'o']]
for i in range(0,3):
    new = copy.deepcopy(original_2D[:])
    new[0][i] = 'X'
    print new
```