# copying a nested list, then updating values in only the new list

Tags: python, list, updating

I have a nested list, which I make a new copy of (IDs are different). Then when I try to use indices to update a list within the new list, it ends up updating the values in both the pre and post copied lists.

I took a look at some other similar questions that talk about mutability but I'm not 100% sure I understand how it works in my specific case.

Heres some example code:

```
numTrials = 2

abPositions = [[1, 'a.png', [9, 9, 9, 9]], [1, 'b.png', [9, 9, 9, 9]]]

abPositionsRotated = list(abPositions)

for i in xrange(numTrials):
    abPositionsRotated[i][2] = [0,0,0,0]

print abPositions
print abPositionsRotated
```

so as I update the 2 sublists within abPositionsRotated, the same lists get updated in abPositions as well and I'm not sure why. As far as I know, there is no link between the abPositions and abPositionsRotated, so I dont understand why changes to one affects the other

Comment: _"As far as I know, there is no link between the abPositions and abPositionsRotated"_ Just because you made a copy of the _outer list_, doesn't mean you made a copy of the _inner_ list. `abPositionsRotated[0]` and `abPositions[0]` are the same object.

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25035664/3001761) - `list(...)` is also a **shallow copy**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing with nested lists in Python can be a bit tricky for people who aren't used to it. What you're doing is creating a separate list, but where each nested list in the separate (outer) lists points to the same memory. The solution here is simple, however: use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module:

```
from copy import deepcopy

abPositions = [[1, 'a.png', [9, 9, 9, 9]], [1, 'b.png', [9, 9, 9, 9]]]
abPositionsRotated = deepcopy(abPositions)

# Now any operation on abPositionsRotated will only apply to it
```

On a completely separate note, you should probably have a read over [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is a style guide for Python.